# Mirror a single table to multiple sheets in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have one table in the database sheet in which i would want to paste link to another sheet. However i realised that it is not possible using excel and vba. Is there any ways to reference these tables automatically? Equating the cell ranges is one way that i know of but it is extremely tedious because i have over 50 tables of such. Hard coding these equations are a trouble.This is a basic code I have done to copy paste a table .

```
Sub table()


ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Copy
'This code will run only when the cursor is at activesheet

Sheets("Sheeet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: "paste link to another sheet" - do you mean creating a hyperlink which opens the referenced sheet, or do you want to "mirror" data so it's always the same as in original range. Both are possible (2nd time easiest solution is a pivot table). Also you can put your code in Sheet2's  `OnActivate` event procedure and it does the copy each time you open that sheet. However I don't really understand why do you need exactly the same data on multiple sheets.

Comment: Mirror data. because one of the sheet is the database sheet which contains all tables. these tables are dispersed in several dashboard sheets and whenever i make a change in the database it should automatically amend in all other sheets. i was able to do so with cells but now it concerns tables so i really need the pastelink to reference the tables to each other @MátéJuhász

Comment: @Niva it is possible to mirror data with tables, i suggest to look at Data -> Existing Connections and google on this (only issue I so far found is that it doesn't copy 1 on 1 it rearranges the order in rows)

Comment: Its more of creating connections rather than to mirror the data more of they should refernce each other so that updating would be done at a single point of interaction instead of amending every single sheet @DragonSamu

Comment: @Niva then Existing connections is exactly what you want as it links the tables and updates the data. you can link Excel Tables, when you click on the button on the 2nd tab Tables you can link tables together and make a new table in a different wb or sheet that links to another table

Comment: But it is done manually right?:) i have to constantly be doing the connections. I have many tables of such @DragonSamu

Comment: The connection is done once per table and then updates on refresh. Thr other way is to automate a connection process with table connections this is also possible

Comment: Yu[ I have up to 50 tables doing it would be so tedious. Do you know those ways of automation? @DragonSamu

Comment: @Niva I will post an example later

Comment: Very much appreicated. Do comment when youve posted. Thanks alot! @DragonSamu

Comment: @Niva  example is posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to add `Table Connections` to a new `Workbook` and a way to `Refresh` the tables.

The code steps through each `ListObject` in `ListObjects` (`Tables`), `.Add`'s the connection to the new `Workbook` and places the `Table` into the `Worksheet`.
It then creates a new `Worksheet` and process the next `ListObject`.

You can change the `Workbook` and `Worksheet` names + path to your needs.

*Do note that for unknown reasons to me the `Table` mixes the rownumbers up when placing them into the new `Worksheet`, it however doesn't mix the `Columns`.

AddTableConnectionsToNewWB code:

```
Sub AddTableConnectionsToNewWB()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tblConn As ListObjects
Dim wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = Workbooks("TableConnections.xlsm")
Set tblConn = Workbooks("TestBook3.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects
For Each tbl In tblConn
    wb.Connections.Add2 "WorksheetConnection_TestBook3.xlsm!" & tbl, _
    "", "WORKSHEET;H:\Projects\TestBook3.xlsm", "TestBook3.xlsm!" & tbl, 7, True, _
    False

    If wb.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then
        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=4, Source:=ActiveWorkbook. _
        Connections("WorksheetConnection_TestBook3.xlsm!" & tbl), Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1")).TableObject
        .RowNumbers = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshStyle = 1
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = tbl.Name
        .Refresh
    End With
    wb.Worksheets.Add after:=wb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Else

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=4, Source:=ActiveWorkbook. _
        Connections("WorksheetConnection_TestBook3.xlsm!" & tbl), Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1")).TableObject
        .RowNumbers = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshStyle = 1
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = tbl.Name
        .Refresh
    End With
    If tblConn.Item(tblConn.Count).Name <> tbl.Name Then
        wb.Worksheets.Add after:=wb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Refresh code (this can also be done by simply clicking the refresh all button in Table Tools):

```
Sub RefreshTableConnections()

Dim wb As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb = Workbooks("TableConnections.xlsm")
wb.RefreshAll
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```