# How can I edit the text of Excel table column headers that are the same across all sheets in the workbook?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel workbook that has ~100 sheets in it, and each sheet is a table whose headers are exactly the same. I have edited the text of the headers in my blank "to copy" sheet, but I now need to copy those changes across each and every existing sheet (the rest of which have data in them that I cannot lose/change).

I have already tried using Shift+click to select all the sheets, but cannot edit the header because they are already formatted as tables and I get the "Cannot make changes to a table or XML mapping when multiple sheets are selected." error. So I either need a way to select every sheet and make them not a table anymore (temporarily) so that I can make the bulk change, or find some other way of doing this change while they are still a table.

Thanks for your time and advice.

Answer (score 0):

[Mirror a single table to multiple sheets in excel using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391223/mirror-a-single-table-to-multiple-sheets-in-excel-using-vba)

You might see this solution, As it is not possible to change multiple sheets while they are formatted as tables .. you might do the changes if your sheets are not formatted as sml or tables.